# Entity Framework code first - abstract class and loosely coupled derived classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
  ///
}
```

In another assembly, which is resolved via Unity

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
}
```

My repository

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
  IDbSet<MyBaseClass> MyStuff{ get; set; }
}
```

What are my options to make EF generate the proper tables? Not using Fluent. EF complains it can't find a deriving class (duh). What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Are you ready for the answer "do use Fluent"?

Comment: I think the concept is that you need to identify a discriminator field that can help EF keep the classes and decide what type they are. I do however not remember the syntax for this, or I would've given you a full answer on it. I'm sure someone else can help you though

Comment: If I were to use Fluent, how would that help me, when the final class is only known after the Unity's resolve?

Comment: I am now trying to solve the issue by defining my MyClass in a separate assembly, which I add as reference to the EF project. However, EF does not find my derived class, because it is not in the same assembly as the base class. What the heck?